# Why are some files are not being added do my zipfile

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip, python-zipfile

I have the following code:

```
with ZipFile('deploy.zip', 'w') as deploy:
    if os.path.isfile(artifact.source):
        deploy.write(artifact.source, artifact.target)
    else:
        for base, dirs, files in os.walk(artifact.source):
            for file_ in files:
                source = os.path.join(base, file_)
                target = os.path.join(base[base.index(artifact.target):], file_)
                deploy.write(source, target)
```

when this code finish, only the files that match when the `artifact.source` is a file are added to the deploy.zip. And in some cases `artifact.source` will be a directory (i have tested this case too) ad the `for` part will be executed.

The result of the following lines are valid and source exists for every iteration:

```
source = os.path.join(base, file_)
target = os.path.join(base[base.index(artifact.target):], file_)
```

Here the full code that i'm working: https://gist.github.com/khaoz/9b04d87b0900fba780f0
Set config.project_root to something like "c:\temp" and remove the import config line.
OBS: I'm a Python newbie, so ignore some crap code that  you will see :P

And here a example of my csv file: https://gist.github.com/khaoz/e9a59390f415f22d46db

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: so when you print source and target before every ``deploy.write`` they're as you expect ?

Comment: Short answer: The `for` loop in the `else` clause is never being executed. You have a single `if` statement executing once in the `ZipFile` context.

Comment: @sotapme yes. Everuthing is ok.

Comment: @martineau the `for` is exucuted. I have made all tests.

Comment: In the code shown in your question, it's only executed when `os.path.isfile(artifact.source)` isn't True.

Comment: @martineau and this will happens :). The source for the `artifac.source` is a csv with files and directories to be copied.

Comment: If `artifac.source` is a csv file, you will have to open it and process its contents, line by line. This will not happen automatically in the `ZipFile.write()` method.

Comment: @martineau yeap, i know and it's exactly what i'm doing. :) I will poste my code and a sample csv to clarify things.

Comment: You really need to include enough source code in your question from the start so everyone doesn't waste time guessing about what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem. Sometimes, sleep is the best solution form some problems

I was doing:

```
for artifact in artifacts:
    if not artifact.name in contents:
        contents.append(artifact.name)

    with ZipFile('deploy.zip', 'w') as deploy:
        if os.path.isfile(artifact.source):
            deploy.write(artifact.source, artifact.target)
        else:
            for base, dirs, files in os.walk(artifact.source):
                for file_ in files:
                    source = os.path.join(base, file_)
                    target = os.path.join(base[base.index(artifact.target):], file_)
                    deploy.write(source, target)
```

But for every iteration in the artifacts close and open a new `deploy.zip` file.

The right way to do this is:

```
with ZipFile('deploy.zip', 'w') as deploy:
    for artifact in artifacts:
        if not artifact.name in contents:
            contents.append(artifact.name)

        if os.path.isfile(artifact.source):
            deploy.write(artifact.source, artifact.target)
        else:
            for base, dirs, files in os.walk(artifact.source):
                for file_ in files:
                    source = os.path.join(base, file_)
                    target = os.path.join(base[base.index(artifact.target):], file_)
                    deploy.write(source, target)
```

And everything works as expected.

Thank you very much for everyone that tried to help. Next time i will post the full source code or at last, some lines more. :)

Comment: We live and learn - at least you didn't drop the bomb "It doesn't work" then sit back and wait - sleeping on it is always a good thing.

Comment: As I said in an early comment, it was a `for` loop problem.

Comment: Agreed. But not because the `else:` was not being executed. Anyway I apologize for not posting the entire source code in the initial post. :)

Answer (score 1):

**JUST FYI**

My interpretation of what you did, this seems to work.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from collections import namedtuple
import os

Artifact =  namedtuple('Artifact', ['source', 'target'])
artifact =  Artifact(source="Mongodb", target="g")

with ZipFile('deploy.zip', 'w') as deploy:
    if os.path.isfile(artifact.source):
        print "F"
        print "\n", artifact.source
        print "\n", artifact.target
        deploy.write(artifact.source, artifact.target)
    else:
        for base, dirs, files in os.walk(artifact.source):
            for file_ in files:
                print "base", base, file_
                source = os.path.join(base, file_)
                target = os.path.join(base[base.index(artifact.target):], file_)
                print "f"
                print "\t", source
                print "\t", target
                deploy.write(source, target)
```

`unzip -l deploy.zip | tail`

```
     2591  01-09-13 21:26   godb/Sortif/scratch.py
     2010  01-15-13 20:20   godb/Sortif/sortif_model.py
     2495  01-15-13 20:22   godb/Sortif/sortif_model.pyc
      161  01-15-13 20:45   godb/Sortif/sortif_scratch.py
        0  01-08-13 12:05   godb/Sortif/sortif/__init__.py
        0  01-08-13 12:05   godb/Sortif/sortif/models/__init__.py
     1408  01-21-13 18:05   godb/ZeroMQ/client.py
     3044  01-21-13 17:51   godb/ZeroMQ/controller.py
 --------                   -------
 11137644                   967 files
```

I'm unsure what you're trying to achieve with `base[base.index(artifact.target):]` are you wanting to change the prefix ? Because running it on my Mongodb directory `target` had to appear in the directory of the file `base`.

I'm unsure how you expect to drive the code as it seems that `artifact.source` is a constant. So first time around it finds a file and it will never do the part where it's looking for directory.

Shouldn't it be

```
with ZipFile('deploy.zip', 'w') as deploy:
    for artifact in articats:
        if os.path.isfile(artifact.source):
            ...
```

Comment: You're right about change the prefix; remove it to be more exact. It's not needed in my zip. `artifact.source` is not constant. It's a path that is loaded from a csv file. I will commit my code in my github repository tomorrow and share here to give more context.